# How to get Button element inside several shadow roots of html page (Metamask) using JS?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom, metamask

I need to get the button to connect the Metamask wallet to Metis network (https://decentralize.metis.io/) using Javascript.

I want to get the Metamask button in below screen:
[But the button is hidden hin shadow root of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VujlQ.png)

I tried to use below script to access the Metamask button but I cannot

```
document.querySelector('w3m-modal').shadowRoot.querySelector('wui-flex style').shadowRoot.querySelector('wui-card').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-router').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-connect-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('wui-flex').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('wui-list-wallet')[1].shadowRoot.querySelector('button').click();
```

But it cannot run and return the error. Could you please help to review and advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below to click on the Metamask

```
document.querySelector('w3m-modal').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-router').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-connect-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('wui-flex').querySelector('wui-list-wallet:nth-child(3)').shadowRoot.querySelector('button').click();
```

Comment: Great for your support. It is working well. I'd like to deeply learn on this. Do you have any reference to ref? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is placed inside several `shadow-roots` that are not rendered at the same moment after click on connect button.

You should wait for every internal `shadow-root` to be rendered and only then check it's structure and get another Shadow DOM.

You can implement function `waitFor` that waits for function value to be truthy and return it's value and function `drillIntoShadowRoots` that loops through shadow host and wait for it's internal structure to be rendered.
After last structure is rendered, you get target element.

Modal shadow-hosts have tags correspondingly `'w3m-modal', 'w3m-router', 'w3m-connect-view', 'wui-list-wallet'`

```js
let waitFor = async (action, timeoutMs = 10000, pollIntervalMs = 500) => {
  let isTimeout = false;
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    isTimeout = true;
  }, timeoutMs);
  let result;
  while (!isTimeout && !result) {
    result = await action();
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, pollIntervalMs));
  }

  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  if (isTimeout) {
    throw new Error('Timeout exceeded!');
  } else {
    return result;
  }
};

async function drillIntoShadowRoots(hostsSelectors, targetSelector) {
  let targetElement;
  const elementGetter = (s) => (targetElement ?? document).querySelector(s).shadowRoot;
  for (const selector of hostsSelectors) {
    targetElement = await waitFor(() => elementGetter(selector));
  }
  return waitFor(() => targetElement.querySelector(targetSelector));
}

let openModalElement = await drillIntoShadowRoots(['w3m-button', 'w3m-connect-button'], '[data-testid=connect-button]');
openModalElement.click();
const walletConnectElement = await drillIntoShadowRoots(['w3m-modal', 'w3m-router', 'w3m-connect-view', 'wui-list-wallet'], 'button');
walletConnectElement.click();
```